# Requiring password on all pages on a website, except one

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have a .htaccess with authorization, that runs for all parts of an internal website. However, I need to remove the required authorization for one single location.

I've tried using `<Files>` and `<FilesMatch>` in .htaccess to set "Allow Any" for the location, but it doesn't work.

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
AuthName     "Who are you ?"
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
AuthType     Basic
Require valid-user
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 90.185.193.91
<Files "/upload/add_image">
Allow from any
</Files>
Satisfy Any
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Files "/upload/add_image">
Allow from all
Satisfy Any
</Files>
```